# Pydantic merge two members (Fields)

Tags: python, environment-variables, pydantic

I have a example were I have an .env file what contains two variables:

```
PROJECT_NAME="dummy"
DB_URL=postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/
```

In my config.py

```
class DummyConfig(BaseSettings):

    PROJECT: str = Field(...)

    DB_URL: str = Field(...)
```

Now depending on what project I will run, the PROJECT variable will be changed. I want to create full database url by concatenating PROJECT + DB_URL, and that needs to be a new (or in DB_URL) variable in config class. so in this example the result will be :

```
postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/dummy
```

In class Config I want to have something like this:

```
class DummyConfig(BaseSettings):

    PROJECT: str = Field(...)

    DB_URL: str = Field(...) + PROJECT #this is for illustration purpose, I know it does not work
```

I have studied this post: [Pydantic: How to use one field's value to set values for other fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63676411/pydantic-how-to-use-one-fields-value-to-set-values-for-other-fields)

But I do not understand (nor I can ask questions because of low points) how to do this.
The OP was using *user_dict* that I assume was instantiated somewhere in the code. I do not have any dictionary, I am exclusively loading variable trough .env file.

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way for you to achieve this goal is by going around pydantic and just using a property.

```
class DummyConfig(BaseSettings):

    PROJECT: str = Field(...)

    DB_URL: str = Field(...)

    @property
    def FULL_DB_URL(self) -> str:
         return f"{self.DB_URL}/{self.PROJECT}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge them inside environment variable

```
PROJECT_NAME="dummy"
FIRST_VARIABLE=postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/

DB_URI=${FIRST_VARIABLE}${PROJECT_NAME}
```